# What is the correct way to make logging less verbose (chromedp)?

Tags: go, e2e-testing

My question is this package-specific: https://github.com/knq/chromedp/

This is just a glimpse of a log when running **chromedp** `Action`s. It is not event an Action-related piece. What is the correct way to make the logging silent or less verbose?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple:

Code taken from their sample:

```
// create chrome instance
c, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithLog(log.Printf))

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

change to

```
// create chrome instance
c, err := cdp.New(ctxt) // no WithLog() option

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Didn't tested</sub>

I have no expirience with that package, but accourding the usage example, cbp initialized with the log function:

```
// create chrome instance
c, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithLog(log.Printf)) <- in this case log.Printf
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I assume you can set log level for the `log.Printf` with `log.SetFlags(0)`

```
// create chrome instance
log.SetFlags(0)
c, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithLog(log.Printf))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

or pass an empty function(or initialize without a log function).

There is also `Discard` to disable logging at all, `log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)`